# Getting true random numbers from secure enclave in iPhone?

Tags: swift, trng

Is it possible to get true random numbers from the secure enclave in the iPhone? I read the secure enclave includes a TRNG. I'm not sure if it's possible to use this to get random numbers or if it's for internal use of the secure enclave only. Any ideas?

I have read some official Apple documentation about the secure enclave which states it does have a TRNG, but haven't found any code samples or any information on how to use it, if even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct access is exposed to the secure enclave via the `CryptoKit` module, but this can only be used for NIST P-256 signature operations via the `SecureEnclave.P256` namespace.
There's no *direct* TRNG functionality exposed via the secure enclave.

In Swift, random values are generated using the [`SystemRandomNumberGenerator` by default](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator) (such as when you call `Bool.random()`).
The documentation states that the actual source of this data depends on the platform, but on Apple platforms this internally uses `arc4random_buf(3)`, which itself is seeded by `getentropy(2)`.

This implies that any random data generated from `SystemRandomNumberGenerator` is ultimately from `getentropy(2)` which, [according to Apple's security documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/seca0c73a75b/web), sources its data from the kernel's CPRNG.
This CPRNG is **seeded** from the Secure Enclave's hardware TRNG (among other sources), depending on availability.

Despite the TRNG being an implementation detail of the kernel, you can consider the kernel's CPRNG a secure source of random data.
As this source of random data is exposed by default to `.random()` APIs in Swift on Apple platforms, you can expect high-quality random data by default.